# Micronaut default Jackson version

Tags: java, micronaut

I have started working on Micronaut (1.2.6) and trying to spin up a twitter finagle server within the application as we plan to use twitter finagle due to legacy reasons instead of out of the box Rest controller(from micronaut). When I run the application I am getting the following exception

```
Caused by: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Scala module 2.8.4 requires Jackson Databind version >= 2.8.0 and < 2.9.0
at com.fasterxml.jackson.module.scala.JacksonModule.setupModule(JacksonModule.scala:66)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.module.scala.JacksonModule.setupModule$(JacksonModule.scala:51)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.module.scala.DefaultScalaModule.setupModule(DefaultScalaModule.scala:18)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.registerModule(ObjectMapper.java:751)
at com.twitter.finagle.toggle.JsonToggleMap$.<init>(JsonToggleMap.scala:82)
at com.twitter.finagle.toggle.JsonToggleMap$.<clinit>(JsonToggleMap.scala)
```

I can see microaut is automatically pulling jackson-databind 2.9.9.3. How can i override the default version of jackson to be used by micronaut? is there a property I can configure

Comment: "is there a property I can configure" - Yes.  Are you using Maven or Gradle?

Comment: I am using gradle, I tried configuring in gradle.properties (jackson.version=2.8.0) but that didnt worked and my dependencies for jackson were still 2.9.9.3

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the [1.2.7 Micronaut BOM](http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/io/micronaut/micronaut-bom/1.2.7/micronaut-bom-1.2.7.pom) you will see there are several properties for jackson versions depending on which dependencies you want to control.

Based on the error message I would assume you want to change `jackson.databind.version`.

Comment: Even after i have added --- jackson.databind.version=2.8.5
jackson.version=2.8.5
jackson.modules.version=2.8.5
jackson.datatype.version=2.8.5 ---- in my gradle.properties, I can still see jackson 2.9.9 jars in my classpath

Comment: You should generate a dependency report and see what is pulling 2.9.9 in.

Comment: If all you are doing is setting `jackson.databind.version=2.8.5` (and the others) in a property file, that won't affect anything.  You will need to reference those versions in `build.gradle`.

Comment: As a test, add something like https://gist.github.com/jeffbrown/09588d38180a44d1b198e1ef0d88658c and see if you get the desired dependency.